# Why is my function ending (using external library)

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, try-catch, ccxt

I need your help with some error handling. I'm using an external library but have no clue of what's happening with the error. 
Here's my code:

```
//file name = playground.js    
var ccxt = require("ccxt");
    ccxt.exchanges.map(r => {
      let exchange = new ccxt[r]();
      let ticks = exchange
        .fetchTickers()
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res);
        })
        .catch(e => {
          console.log(e);
        });
    });
```

To execute it correctly, you'll need to install the external library: `ccxt` via npm: `npm i ccxt --save`
and I get the following error:

```
.../node_modules/ccxt/js/base/Exchange.js:407
        throw new NotSupported (this.id + ' fetchTickers not supported yet')
        ^

Error: _1broker fetchTickers not supported yet
    at _1broker.fetchTickers (.../node_modules/ccxt/js/base/Exchange.js:407:15)
    at ccxt.exchanges.map.r (.../playground.js:41:6)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (.../playground.js:38:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:676:10)
```

Basically, what the library helps me with is:

- Make automatic request to different servers
- Organize the responses in uniformed objects
- Handle most of the errors that are returned by the servers

In my example, the error returned is related with the fact that the server doesn't support the function I'm using. To put it in simpler words: 
I make a request that server1 might be able to handle but that server2 isn't able to respond to yet.

The `ccxt.exhanges` in the code returns an Array of the differents servers that are being handled by the library.

The problem is not so much that I get the error... I'm OK with not getting info back from every server but that my function literaly stops once it gets to the error. The `.map` loop doesn't go all the way to the end...

[ccxt publishes some information on Error Handling](https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt/wiki/Manual#error-handling) but I'm not sure what I can do with it (noob in the place sorry guys).

I hope my question is clear enough and hasn't been already asked!

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Hey Nandu! Thanks for posting! I'm not sure you've fully read the question though: The method is actually supported by some servers and other no. In that case, `_1broker` is not supported. The objective is not to support it but to handle the error correctly.

Comment: I'm not sure where the others left, but if anyone has any idea how to handle this one, that'd be great!

Comment: I don't know the difference but can you try using `fetchTicker()` instead of `fetchTickers()` or is that entirely un related? For handling the error, `try/catch`?

Comment: Hey again Nandu! Thanks for keeping up :). I've checked. I feel that I'm not handling correctly the error in my code. That something is missing for the loop to carry on after the error is raised. The source throws the error as a class: `class BaseError extends Error`. Thing is that when it is raised by my code the loop simply stops. How can I arrange that so that the loop goes on?

Comment: Got it, Sorry I overlooked again. Add a `try/catch` block?

Comment: That's actually a solution (I guess) but I'm not sure how to implement it correctly...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a slightly better version of it:

```
var ccxt = require("ccxt");
ccxt.exchanges.forEach(r => {

    let exchange = new ccxt[r]();

    if (exchange.hasFetchTickers) { // ← the most significant line

        let ticks = exchange
            .fetchTickers()
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res);
            })
            .catch(e => {
                console.log(e);
            });
    }  
});
```

Comment: Can't compete against the guy who wrote ccxt !! Thanks Igor!

Answer (score 1):

Can you please check if this might work. I replaced `map` with `forEach` because all you are trying to do is loop though the exchanges array.

```
//file name = playground.js    
var ccxt = require("ccxt");
ccxt.exchanges.forEach(r => {
  let exchange = new ccxt[r]();

  try {
    let ticks = exchange
    .fetchTickers()
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res);
    })
    .catch(e => {
      console.log(e);
    });
  } catch(err) {
    // PRINT THE err IF NEEDED
    console.log("CONTINUING THE LOOP BECAUSE fetchTickers is not supported");
  }  
});
```

Comment: You're the absolute best Nandu! Thanks!

Comment: Wonderful! Please learn about `try/catch` it is a must to know thing in any programming language.